# How to set column value as false

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I want to update a column "enabled" to false using Gin framework in Go. I know that it doesn't allow the column to be set as false by default, so I wrote the below code to handle that.

```
if err := db.Model(&subscription).Update(map[string]interface{}{"enabled": false}).Error; err != nil {//do something}
```

Somehow, this doesn't seem to be working anymore. What is wrong in this code?

This is my model:

```golang
type Subscription struct {
    gorm.Model
    Enabled            bool   `gorm:"DEFAULT:True"`
    Deleted            bool   `gorm:"DEFAULT:False"`
    UserID             uint   `gorm:"not null"`
    SubscriptionTypeID uint   `gorm:"not null"`
    Cap                int    `gorm:"DEFAULT:-1"`
    DateOfMonth        string `gorm:"DEFAULT:'0'"`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Updates` method to do it in the way you have tried. This also works for multiple columns.

```
if err := db.Model(&subscription).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"enabled": false}).Error; err != nil {//do something}
```

Also, you can use the `Update` method to update the single column.

```
if err := db.Model(&subscription).Update("enabled", false).Error; err != nil {//do something}
```

[Here](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Update-single-column) you can find more variations on how to update a single column or multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Ankita Gupta, You should declare you model like this:

```
type MyModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    Enabled bool `gorm:"default:false"`
}
```

In this way the boolean default value is false